# How to prefix the contents of an array with java

Tags: java

So if you have an array of strings and the contents of the event how do you label the event number without an "arraylist" like the array in the picture.

```
    public static final String[] EVENTS = {
            "Breakfast at Tiffany's",
            "My Dinner with Andre",
            "Attack of the Killer Tomatoes!",
            "State Fair",
            "Go to White Castle with Harold and Kumar",
            "My Best Friend's Wedding",
            "Soylent Green for Lunch",
            "Groundhog Day",
            "The Arrival of a Train",
            "The Breakfast Club"
    };
    public static void printMyEvenList(){

        for(String i: EVENTS){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOKaD.png)

Comment: By using [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: please to look the image

Answer (score 1):

The `for-each` loop hides the iterator (or index), use a traditional loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < EVENTS.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", i, EVENTS[i]);
}
```

**or** you could keep your own additional counter. Like,

```
int i = 0;
for (String s : EVENTS) {
    System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", i, s);
    i++;
}
```